# Why is this code printing trash at the end? Why is strlen returning uncorrect values?

Tags: c, fgets, strlen

I am running the following program

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char fileName[NAMESIZE];
    char buffer[BUFFSIZE];
    buffer[0] = 0;
    int bytes;

    bytes = read(0 ,fileName, NAMESIZE);
    char command[COMMANDSIZE];
    char outAux[TAGSIZE];
    fileName[bytes - 1] = 0;

    sprintf(command, "minisat %s | grep \"Number of v\" -A2 | sed 's/|//g'| sed 's/: */: /g' | sed 's/^ *//g'", fileName);

    FILE * fp;
    fp = popen(command, "r");

    while(fgets(outAux, TAGSIZE, fp)){
        strcat(buffer, outAux);
    }

    pclose(fp);
    write(1, buffer, BUFFSIZE);
    
    return 0;
}
```

From what I understand, fgets does put a 0 at the end. However, the output is the following:

```
Number of variables: 3                                         
Number of clauses: 2                                         
Parse time: 0.00 s                                       
(trash)
```

It correctly prints what I wanted to but then it starts prnting trash, as if there was no 0 at the end

I tried fixing this by forcing a 0 by doing the following: saving the length of outAux in every iteration of the while loop, adding that to a counter buffLen, and then doing buffer[buffLen] = 0

However, this fails because strlen is not returning the length of outAux. For example, the line "Number of variables: 3\n" has a length of 64 according to strlen

How can I fix my problem? (and if possible I would also like to know why strlen is returning uncorrect values)

EDIT: The original issue came from me incorrectly using write. However, I still have my original question. If I run the following code:

```
fgets(outAux, TAGSIZE, fp));
printf("%s", outAux);
printf("%d", strlen(outAux));
```

I get the following output:

```
Number of variables: 3
64
```

Why is strlen returning this large value?

Comment: Because you are sendign `BUFFSIZE` bytes to the output, instead of the number actually in the buffer.

Comment: but shouldn't write stop as soon as it finds the 0 at the end?. Also, I can't correctly send the number of bytes actually in the buffer because strlen is returning weird values

Comment: You haven't used the `strlen` you wrote about.

Comment: No, `write` writes the number of bytes you tell it to write.

Comment: @WeatherVane not in the code, I said how I used it in comments

Comment: Any particular reason you are using `read` and `write` with STDIN/STDOUT, as opposed to more conventional `printf/scanf`? The later would handle your issue with nul-terminated strings correctly.

Comment: @WeatherVane then why is the trash printed at the end variable in size?

Comment: Please read my first comment. You write the whole buffer regardless of its usage.

Comment: but the buffer is fixed in size, that's what I don't get

Comment: You can store a 3 byte string in a 10 byte `buf`. But, if you use `write(1, buf, 10)`, you are going to get 7 bytes of garbage after the first 3 bytes.

Comment: ok, thanks. I edited my original question because I still don't get why strlen is returning such a large value

Comment: Please read up on creating a [mcve].

Comment: Please try stepping through the code in a debugger.

Comment: I think previous comments mentioned the cause, but I'd like to add a note about the `read`, Since you're using `read` you have to check the number of bytes you got from it and if the bytes in the result are `null-terminated` or it may cause problems sometimes, you can check this by `if (!filename[bytes])`.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what minisat is or does, but I bet that TAGSIZE equals 64 and that minisat just doesn't output anything that fgets recognizes as newline. Therefore fgets just captures the pipe output, and the "trash" you see is just the remainder of whatever was in the buffer at the beginning.

Your code is prone to all sorts of undefined behavior due to buffer overruns.

Comment: This is possible, but you have not really explained the root cause.